# JDBC Pool for Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat6, tomcat7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ClassCastException DataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983403/classcastexception-datasource-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-sql-connectionpooldatasour)

**How to make tomcat-jdbc.jar work with Tomcat 6?**

We have an application that was designed to be deployed in Tomcat 6 however due to fixes we did, we needed to put JDBC pool codes, that I believe only works with Tomcat 7? Since tomcat 6 is already in our production server, I may need to make JDBC pool work with Tomcat 6?

*I was doing my local development for our application and use Tomcat7 for debugging, that I forgot that we use Tomcat6 in production**

Update:

When I run in tomcat 6 I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
```

When it works without problems in Tomcat7...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly easy, I am running Tomcat JDBC for more than a year now on Tomcat 6. Configure it as you would configure a normal `DataSource` but put the JAR in Tomcat's `lib` dir and add the [`factory`](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) attribute with the value `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory` to your `Resource` element.

Off topic: Just a tip, *always* use the same Tomcat version for testing as you would use for production.

Comment: I have configured tomcat 7 jdbc in tomcat 6 for more than a year now with the way that you suggest and it works fine apart from an exception that I get every now and then related to the PoolCleaner. Do you get this exception too? Here is more details about the exception http://stackoverflow.com/q/17473483/2105307

Comment: @NikosDim, I don't ever had this one. I will continue on the question mentioned.