# ClassCastException DataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat7

I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
```

When I try to run my webapp (in Tomcat6) that use tomcat jdbc pool that seamlessly work with Tomcat7

I have included these jars already in tomcat 6 lib folder:

```
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-juli.jar
```

What could be the problem?

**Update:**

```
protected static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
    String jndiName = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDBHrd";
    ConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = (ConnectionPoolDataSource) cxt.lookup(jndiName); // ClassCastException here....
    PooledConnection pooledConnection = dataSource.getPooledConnection();
    Connection conn = pooledConnection.getConnection();
    return conn; // Obtain connection from pool
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDBHrd"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          testOnReturn="false"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="30000"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
          maxActive="5000"
          minIdle="10"
          maxWait="10000"
          initialSize="20"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          logAbandoned="false"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
          jmxEnabled="true"
          jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
            org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
          username="sa"
          password="password"
          driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.114.130/MyDB"/>
```

When I change the "type":

```
 type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource"
```

I get this warning:

```
WARNING: javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource is not a valid class name/type for this JNDI factory.
```

Causing the `getConnection()` to return NULL.

**Imports:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource;
import javax.sql.PooledConnection;

import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

Comment: This seems issue with wrong imports. Make sure you have valid imports.

Comment: Which wrong imports? You mean in the code? But it worked without errors in tomcat7

Comment: Yes in code. I would suggest post some code and add more information on when you are getting this error.

Comment: @Nambari Ok I have placed the java code

Comment: [Reference](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2241501) Missing Configuration as i suspect that from [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/459897/tomcat-classcastexception-datasource-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-sql-connectionpoo)

Comment: can you post imports from your code

Comment: [More Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506859/datasource-or-connectionpooldatasource-for-application-server-jdbc-resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an end-user you should never ever have to use a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` directly. It is intended as a factory for physical connections (the `PooledConnection`). That `PooledConnection` is kept in the connectionpool. When you do a `DataSource.getConnection`, the datasource will check out a `PooledConnection` from the pool, and return the logical connection obtained using `PooledConnection.getConnection()` to you as the end-user, and returning the physical connection to the pool when that logical `Connection` is closed.

So the construct is

```
User -- uses --> DataSource (with connectionpooling) -- uses --> ConnectionPoolDataSource
```

Or

```
ConnectionPoolDataSource --> creates PooledConnection --> DataSource --> returns Connection --> User
```

The use of a `DataSource` is independent of the fact if that `DataSource` provides connectionpooling or not (it should be transparent to you).

See also a previous answer of mine to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12651163/466862

In other words your code should be changed to:

```
protected static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
    String jndiName = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDBHrd";
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) cxt.lookup(jndiName);
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    return conn;
}
```